Question on exponential functions and drawing suitable lines on the graph
This question is from an exercise in an Edexcel Further Pure Mathematics book. Parts a, b, and c were fairly easy for me. For part a, I found the corresponding values of y using a calculator and in part b I drew the curve with no problems. In part (c) I rearranged the question:
$$\begin{align*}
e^x &= 10 \\
\frac 1 2 e^x &= 5 \\
\frac 1 2 e^x + 3 &= 8
\end{align*}$$
Then used the graph to find the value of $x$ for which the function was equal to $8$.
However, I did not know where to start with part (d). I tried using the power rule of logs to bring $1-x$ to the power of $4$, but I didn’t know what to do after that. Could someone explain how to solve part (d)?

The question:


Well, raising to the power of $e$ first, we get
$$
e^x = 4(1-x)
$$
Multiply by $\frac 1 2$:
$$
\frac 1 2 e^x = 2(1-x)
$$
Add $3$:
$$
\frac 1 2 e^x + 3 = 2(1-x) + 3 
$$
Now simplify:
$$
\frac 1 2 e^x + 3 = -2x+5
$$
So you have, from part (b), the curve $y = \frac 1 2 e^x+3$. Find where it intersects the line $y=-2x+5$.


Thanks for answering!
